# Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, gcc

Below is a block of code from my program. I'm getting error of `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` after entering `name` and `age` in first loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct Cricketer
{
    char name[25];
    int age;
    float avg_run;
};

int main(){
struct Cricketer c[3];
int i,j;

for (i=0 ; i<3;i++){
    printf("Enter name: \n");
    scanf("%s",c[i].name);

    printf("Enter age: \n");
    scanf("%d",c[i].age);

    printf("Enter average run: \n");
    scanf("%f",c[i].avg_run);               
}
return 0;
}
```

And I couldn't find what is causing this program.

Comment: No it's not `gcc` (the *compiler*) that crashes. It's your program that does when you run it. As for how to solve it, you first use a debugger to locate where in the program it happens. Please read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: So is your question "How do you debug a core dump?" If so, you should state your platform and/or your preferred debugger.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Then **use the debugger `gdb`** . You fix-my-code question is off-topic.

Comment: A good compiler will warn you about the problem.  If you don't have enough warnings enabled, or don't have a good enough compiler, fix it (add the warning options, or upgrade the compiler).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - too bad I can only vote once on a comment -- that reason, and that reason alone, enabling *Compiler Warnings* would probably resolve 50+% of the questions posted related to C.

Comment: Look carefully at the manual page for `scanf`.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is here:

```
scanf("%d",c[i].age);
```

Change it for:

```
scanf("%d",&(c[i].age));
```

When using `%d` you have to pass the address of the `int` variable. And the same for `floats`:

```
scanf("%f",&(c[i].avg_run));
```

When using scanf, the second argument has to be the address of a variable. With your variable `name` there is no problem because it already refers to the address of the buffer in which you want to store the string.

Comment: And the same for `c[i].avg_run`

Comment: Does it goes same for `name` also ?

Comment: No, for `name` is correct

Comment: @Jesferman Please tell him why it is correct for name and not for other fields...

Comment: Why the extraneous parentheses in `&(c[i].age)` instead of the simpler `&c[i].age`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler only for clarifying the OP we are refering to the address of the variable and not the struct

Comment: I'd be OK with the parentheses if there was a comment about "or, in more idiomatic C, `&c[i].age`" or something along those lines.  Showing the parenthesized version as the only solution isn't so good.

Comment: *Your error is here:* but that line is not even there in the original code. That is not his error, that is the correction. Please rephrase

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya corrected. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @Jesferman - just a note that the parens are for emphasis only, as by C *Operator Precedence Rules* gives higher precedence to both `[ ]` and `'.'` making the parens unnecessary.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes, i put them only for clarifying the OP we are refering to the address of the variable and not the struct

Comment: Yes, that's fair. Remember as you go farther here on S.O., you are stepping into the role of a teacher, helping to pass knowledge and learning along to the next generation of programmers, so  you want to do as good a job as possible (and within reason) to discuss nuances of that particular area of code. Look forward to seeing many more of your answers here.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for help me to improve. Nice to meet kind people here

Answer (score 1):

When using `scanf`, the second argument should be the address of a variable. In your program `c[i].age` and `c[i].avg_run` are the variables themselves and not the addresses. Use the `&` operator to get the address of a variable. For Example, `&(c[i].age)` or just `&c[i].age`.

What you are passing to `scanf` as mentioned above are some numbers which might or might not be valid memory addresses. Thus invoking *undefined behavior*.

`c[i].name` happens to be fine because referring to an array (`name` in this case) by just the name evaluates to the base address of the array.

It is a good idea to have compiler warnings enabled. More important is one reads and understands the warnings. Read your compiler manual for more info.

Comment: Why the extraneous parentheses in `&(c[i].age)` instead of the simpler `&c[i].age`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler :) I can never remember the precedence rules.

Comment: extra parenthesis are optional, you can use  &c[i].age  too and the result will be same.